# Запрос MySQL с выборкой всех строк и подсчетом

Tags: запрос, mysql

Нужно выбрать все строки из таблицы и добавить результирующее поле к строке с подсчетом количества записей из другой таблицы по ключам.
Делаю так:

```
SELECT
  `kindergarten`.`Name`,
  `kindergarten`.`Director`,
  `kindergarten`.`Address`,
  `kindergarten`.`Phone`,
  `kindergarten`.`IdKindergarten`,
  `kindergarten`.`Web`,
  `MaxKids`,
  COUNT(kind.IdKind) AS ActiveKids
FROM
  `kindergarten`
LEFT JOIN
  `kind`
ON
  `kind`.`IdKindergarten` = `kindergarten`.`IdKindergarten`
ORDER BY
  `IdKindergarten` DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Дает одну запись

Comment: [RTFM GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  `kindergarten`.`Name`,
  `kindergarten`.`Director`,
  `kindergarten`.`Address`,
  `kindergarten`.`Phone`,
  `kindergarten`.`IdKindergarten`,
  `kindergarten`.`Web`,
  `MaxKids`,
  COUNT(kind.IdKind) AS ActiveKids
FROM
  `kindergarten`
LEFT JOIN
  `kind`
ON
  `kind`.`IdKindergarten` = `kindergarten`.`IdKindergarten`
ORDER BY
  `IdKindergarten` DESC
GROUP BY
  ActiveKids
LIMIT 20
```